# Distance to a circle vs distance to a line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, circles

A line can be defined as $y = mx+p$, that is, every point that satisfy $y-mx+p=0$. The "$0$" in this equation is a number increasing and decreasing depending on the distance between the point to the line. In other words, the function $f(x, y) = y-mx+p$ takes a point and returns a number increasing and decreasing depending on the distance between the point to the line.

If we place two points $A$ and $B$ at equal distance from the line, we indeed get the same absolute value for $f(A)$ and $f(B)$, which is $0.5$ (great!).

[picture of a line y=0.5x + 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6ndj.png)

If we do the exact same thing with a circle, defined as $f(x, y) = x^2+y^2-r^2$, it **does not work**. We place two points $A$ and $B$ at equal distance from the circle, but the absolute value for the bottom point is *less* (1.75) than the number for the top point (2.25). In other words, we cannot use this equation to know whether two points are at equal distance from the circle.

[circle x2 + y2 = 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxxXj.png)

The question is: why doesn't it work for the circle but works with the line? is it because of the square?

Comment: The square and linear functions are different. Different functions give different results.

Comment: $y=mx+p$ and $y-mx+p=0$ are not equivalent. You’ve made a sign error.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you wrote for the distance from a point to a line is not the formula for the shortest distance from a point to a line; instead, it's actually the *vertical* distance. By the way, it seems that you've also made a typo for the vertical distance formula, because it should be $f(x,y)=y-mx-p$ rather than $f(x,y)=y-mx+p$. The shortest distance, which is the *perpendicular* distance rather than the vertical distance, is given by the formula which you can read all about [here (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line). Essentially, you must also take into account the slope of your line.

As for your circle distance formula, it is not correct. By the distance formula, we know that the shortest distance between a point and a circle is $|\sqrt{(x_1)^2+(y_1)^2}-r|$. Intuitively, we derive this by using the distance formula between a point and the circle's center and subtracting the distance from the locus of the circle to the center of the circle. Using this formula, you would see that both points have a distance of $0.5$ from the circle.

Comment: Ok but even if it doesn't give the actual shortest distance, the formula for the line succeeds at knowing if two points are at equal distance but applying the same principles to the circle, it doesn't work. Of course if we compute the actual distance, we get the good result but why can't we at least know if two points are at equal distance with the circle equation? (I recall it works with the line)

Comment: It is because $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-r^2$ is not the distance from the circle, nor the distance from anything useful. What you have done is subtracted the $r^2$ term from both sides and put it into a function.